# Proper Login using servlets redirect to url

Tags: servlets, authentication

I'm using apache tomcat and a servlet to check username and password from mysql database

HTML page code:

```
<form action="./login" method="POST">
    User name: <input type="text" name="username" size="20"><br>
    Password: <input type="password" name="pwd" size="20">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Servlet Code:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;
public class VerifyLogin extends HttpServlet
{
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res)throws IOException,ServletException
    {
        String n1 = req.getParameter("username");
        String n2 = req.getParameter("pwd");
        res.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();

        try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb","root","paSSword");
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from auth WHERE username=? && password=?");
        ps.setString(1,n1);
        ps.setString(2,n2);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();


        if(rs.next())
        {
            res.sendRedirect("report.html");

        }   
        else
        {
            res.sendRedirect("Invalid.html");
        }

    }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
}
```

web.xml code:

```
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>VerifyLogin</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My directory structure is

```
=============>tomcat
               +webapps
                 +myapp
                   +
                   +report.html
                   +report2.html
                   +xxxx.html
                   +WEB-INF
                       +classes
                       +lib
                       +web.xml
```

I was able to successfully verify and  redirect a user to desired page( report.hmtl),the problem is when user copies the address after login say http://192.168.2.2:8080/myapp/Reports.html and paste the address in another browser he will not be asked to login .

report.html has more links in it, which can be accessed wtihout login if some one knows the link. ALL the .html pages are placed outside WEB-INF folder how can i protect those from (example report2.html,xxx.html) from direct access? without converting the html pages to jsp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In every page you need check any user logged in or not. You can do it by using `Session Management`,

Easiest way is make all your HTML pages into jsp's.

set one variable in your servlet

```
if(rs.next())
        {
            res.sendRedirect("report.html");
            session.setAttribute("userSession", "loggedin");

        }
```

in your jsps check this.

```
<c:if test="${sessionScope.userSession=='loggedin'}">
//rest of the code
<c:else>
//redirect to login
```

Comment: thnaks for reply , can't it be done without converting html to jsp ?? ps: forgot to mention it in  question

Comment: no, u cant check session in HTML, and there is no problem in converting to jsp...

Comment: my problem is that i have 56 html pages outside WEB-INF folder, is there any way can i convert them in a batch automatically ?

Comment: should i also need to add <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>?